# WorkManager and notification not working on firsttime

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

WorkManager with notification not working on firsttime. But working when I open app, after that the notification will work normally.

```
WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).beginWith(listOfWork).enqueue()
```

```
if (workNumber == "1" && stateToAlert1) {
     val strText= settingSharedPreferences1.getString("strText", null)
     val builder = buildNotification(context, "1", strText)
     registerChannel(context, strText, "1")
     with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
          notify(1, builder.build())
     }
}
```

```
private fun buildNotification(context: Context, channelId: String,textToAlert: String?): NotificationCompat.Builder {
     val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
     intent.putExtra("score", Random.nextInt(5, 30))
     intent.putExtra("channelId", channelId)
     val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, channelId.toInt(), intent, 0)
     return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
         .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm)
         .setContentTitle("Notification")
         .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
         .setContentText(textToAlert)
         .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
         .setAutoCancel(false)
}
```

Comment: what is `workNumber `?

Comment: It is inputData of workmanager.

Comment: please debug your app at the `if (workNumber == "1" && stateToAlert1)` condition as `workNumber ` may be not equal to 1 for the first time

Comment: I think your context is null. please check the context notification.

Comment: workNumber is 1 correct ,and I try to put workNumber and stateToAlert1 to sharedPreference when app closed then nothing happened in device file explorer.

Comment: @JavadDehban i try to change PendingIntent.getActivity to  PendingIntent.getService and PendingIntent.getBroadcast but not work. how can to check context when app closed ?

Comment: @iantdroid you can see the log in logcat when spinner select  "No Filters" even if the app closed.

Comment: @JavadDehban I try to change all sharedPreference in worker class to fragment and pass it in inputData but logcat not show any in logcat ....i use Log.e(..........)
(notification will working when I open app)

Comment: I think I must have broadcast receiver ?

Comment: answer : notification not working on emulator only (The cause is still unknown.), But I testing on real device it work ,thanks for all people